# Change CSS in Bing Map elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bing-maps

I'm converting an in-house application from using Google Maps to Bing Maps. The map needs to appear inside a named HTML `div`. Everywhere I've converted them, they render fine, with one exception.

The map is supposed to appear at the bottom of a very long table. Instead, it renders at the top of the page, covering a number of rows. Using the F12 Developer Tools (in IE), we were able to adjust some CSS parameters to get it to render correctly. The problem is, they're inside `divs` inserted by Bing Maps. Looking at the Microsoft Maps API, there are facilties to change numerous options, but not to alter the Bing-generated CSS.

The pertinent CSS:

```
<div class="MicrosoftMap MapTypeId_auto large miniscule" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; 
right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 0; 
cursor: url(http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/7.0.20141118162111.86/cursors/grab.cur), move; 
direction: ltr !important; touch-action: none; background-color: rgb(244, 242, 238);">
```

If we remove `overflow`, thus:

```
<div class="MicrosoftMap MapTypeId_auto large miniscule" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; 
right: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 0; 
cursor: url(http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/7.0.20141118162111.86/cursors/grab.cur), move; 
direction: ltr !important; touch-action: none; background-color: rgb(244, 242, 238);">
```

it renders correctly, in the right location. The code to allocate the map:

```
var newMap = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
   document.getElementById("mapelement"), {
   credentials: "[my credentials]",
   center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(37.6970, -97.8096),
   disableBirdseye: true,
   mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
});
```

And the function that gets called to insert the map, `LoadMaps()`, is called here in the HTML:

```
<body onload="LoadMaps()">
```

We're not using jQuery or any other libraries.

My leading theory is that the Bing Map tries to render before the `mapelement` is loaded, so it just renders at the top. But this wouldn't explain why Google Maps renders into the element fine, and onload is supposed to only be called *after* the entire page is loaded.

Anyone else have experience with Bing Maps and might know what's going on?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the HTML for the mapelement:

```
<table class="tableResult" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="mapCell"><div id="mapelement" style="width: 900px; height: 900px"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table><table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="29"><p style="page-break-before: always"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
```

I know it's weird having hte `div` close outside the table when it starts inside the table, but that's not the problem (and it's kind of a pain to change since it's an aspx page).

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify the Bing generated CSS. Can you provide the CSS you are using to create the div for where the map will be loaded?

Comment: @rbrundritt: Added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a position value for the map. In the style parameter add position:relative;

Comment: Wow, that was it! I thought we tried that, but I guess we just missed it. Thanks so much!